# Combine multiple and repeating values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm retrieving data from DB, and I so far I reached a list of dictionaries. In each dict I'm interested in the keys `title`, `authors`, `publishedAt` and `tickers`. Some dicts have the `tickers` empty, so I ignore those. Some dicts may have a list of multiple `tickers` and multiple `authors`, so in this case I'd like my DataFrame to have one row for each author and ticker, and the `title` and `publishedAt` must repeat thoughout those lines.

Example of dictionary:

```
dict = {'title':'Report',
         'authors':[{'name': 'Mike'},{'name':'John'}],
         'tickers':[{'code':'GOOGL'},{'code':'AAPL'}],
         'publishedAt':'2022-03-31'
        }
```

The desired outcome would be something like:

| Author | Date | Title | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 2022-03-01 | Report | GOOGL |
| Mike | 2022-03-01 | Report | AAPL |
| John | 2022-03-01 | Report | GOOGL |
| John | 2022-03-01 | Report | AAPL |

I was trying to do something like this, where publications is my list of dicts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Author','Date','Title','Ticker'])

for publication in publications:
    qty_tickers = len(publication['tickers'])
    qty_authors = len(publication['authors'])
    qty_total = qty_tickers * qty_authors
    if qty_total >= 1:
        start = len(df)+1
        df.iloc[start:start+qty_total,1:2] = [publication['publishedAt'],publication['title']]
```

This last bit is already not working, as I receive `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (0,1)`.
And I didn't even know how to start with the Authors and Tickers.

Comment: could you include more than 1 line of data? It's not clear at the moment what the optimal solution would be for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of populating the DataFrame dynamically, you should first perform the data wrangling and only then construct the DataFrame with it. In this case, it makes sense to create a list of records/ dictionaries (the rows of the DataFrame) based on `publications`

```
import pandas as pd 

publications = [
    {
    'title':'Report',
    'authors':[{'name': 'Mike'},{'name':'John'}],
    'tickers':[{'code':'GOOGL'},{'code':'AAPL'}],
    'publishedAt':'2022-03-31'
    }, 
    {
    'title':'Something',
    'authors':[{'name': 'Someone'},{'name':'Other'}],
    'tickers':[{'code':'ABC'},{'code':'DEF'}],
    'publishedAt':'2022-03-31'
    }
]
    
records = []

for publication in publications:
    for author in publication['authors']:
        for ticker in publication['tickers']:
            rec = {
                'Author': author['name'],
                'Date': publication['publishedAt'],
                'Title': publication['title'],
                'Ticker': ticker['code']
            }
            records.append(rec)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

    Author        Date      Title Ticker
0     Mike  2022-03-31     Report  GOOGL
1     Mike  2022-03-31     Report   AAPL
2     John  2022-03-31     Report  GOOGL
3     John  2022-03-31     Report   AAPL
4  Someone  2022-03-31  Something    ABC
5  Someone  2022-03-31  Something    DEF
6    Other  2022-03-31  Something    ABC
7    Other  2022-03-31  Something    DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

One example how to get this result would be

```
for author in publication['authors']:
    for ticker in publication['tickers']:
        df = pd.concat([
            df,
            pd.DataFrame({
            'Author': author['name'],
            'Date': publication['publishedAt'],
            'Title': publication['title'],
            'Ticker': ticker['code']
            }, index=[0])
            ])
```

Using `pd.concat()` from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat), this concatenates the original DataFrame `df` with the newly created DataFrame from a dict. Since there was no index, I adjusted the function call to use the first column. You can of course adjust that to your liking.